# MySQL procedure not producing output, but same query used in procedure has results

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

query output is not coming, but if I hard code the mac then working fine.

`CREATE PROCEDURE`NewProc2`(IN mac varchar(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM abc.xyz
 WHERE ate_mac_address ='mac';
END;`

Comment: Can you add your procedure code and calling statement please.

Comment: added,sorry I forget beofre this

Comment: Query is seraching for the string 'mac' I suspect you should remove the quotes.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. 
feeling very happy, issue solved.